# Why is the penalty in the logistic regression likelihood ratio test different from the penalty I specified when fitting the model?

Tags: r, logistic, regression-strategies, rms, regularization

I'm fitting a penalized logistic regression model using the rms package in R. When I print the result, the penalty in the model likelihood ratio test is different from the penalty I used to fit the model. Why is this?

```
library(datasets)
library(rms)
fit = lrm(Species ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris, x=T, y=T)
pen = pentrace(fit, seq(0,5, by=0.1))
pen$penalty # penalty = 1.3
fit <- update(fit, penalty=pen$penalty)
print(fit) # penalty in model LR test  = 0.97
fit$penalty # penalty = 1.3
```